# javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Not trusted server certificate on Galaxy Tab 7 only?

Tags: android, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I have an application which connects to an HTTPS web service. I did not include any certificate in my application because the HTTPS is certified by VeriSign. As such, it should be a trusted certificate already by default even without including the certificate in the device.

I was able to connect to it using a Samsung Galaxy S2. However, in Samsung Galaxy Tab 7, it returns an error: `javax.net.SSLException: Not trusted server certificate on Galaxy Tab 7`. What could be the problem? Does different Android devices trust certificates differently even though the certificate is VeriSign certified? What could I do to fix the problem? Is there a way to configure an Android device to trust VeriSign without modifying the application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are they running different versions of Android?  If this is a website that you control, you'll want to make sure that the proper CA bundle is installed along with the certificate. As far as adding more root CAs to Android... I believe there is something in preferences: `personal > security > credential storage` that might give you more options with regards to SSL certificates.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, their running different versions of Android. The Galaxy Tab 7 is running under Android APi 2.2 while the S2 is running under 4.0.4. It's not a website but an Android application which I made so I have control on it. Upon further searching, it seems that lower versions of Androids lack some certificates. So if I want the Galaxy Tab 7 to trust VeriSign, I should install the certificate using the `Install encrypted certificates from SD Card'?

Comment: That sounds correct -- http://blog.crazybob.org/2010/02/android-trusting-ssl-certificates.html seems to be how you would add your certificate programatically. Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks, Daniel! Just one more thing, it seems that the client can't also access FB (besides from my app) due to an SSL certificate error. Is it possible that something was deleted on the phone? Because the client said, the problem just started a week ago. Is there a way to restore the lost certificates if there is any?

Comment: Lol. The problem is with the time and date. The certificate appears to be invalid because the time and date is not properly set on the device. This cause the application to throw an SSLException. But thanks for answering my question! Didn't know before that this could cause an issue.

Answer (score 3):

put your time and date back to the right time and date and all will be fine

Comment: What in the world? This worked for me haha. Any idea what's going on there?

Comment: @art Ahhh, makes sense now. Thanks!